# Disable/enable confusion: is this an error in the design?

Tags: transistors, bjt, regulations

If Enable_Voltage is at 3.3 V then the disable pin is high and the chip (EMI transformer) is working.

Doesn't that mean the transistor is on and the enable voltage is short-circuited?

Is this the right way to analyse it? Or will the transistor not switch on?

The voltage divider will put 1 V on the base pin.

[image: Disable / Enable Confusion]

Comment: What’s an EMI transformer? Who drew the schematic?

Comment: If R8=0 as drawn, then the enable_voltage is connected directly to Disable(Active_Low), and the rest of the components don't play any role.

Comment: UCC25800-Q1 Ultra-low EMI Transformer Driver for Isolated Bias Supplies. The Schematic is not complete but its only this part that i find confusing.

Comment: @MarkU except as a possible smoke generator.

Comment: does that mean that the transistor will short ?

Answer (score 1):

The [UCC25800-Q1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc25800-q1.pdf) transformer driver has a DIS/FLT input that has a threshold of around 2 volts. It also has a pull-down (probably some kind of current mirror) internally that draws about 0.75mA.

Provided there is a series impedance (represented here by R3) on ENABLE_INPUT the transistor will act as a Vbe multiplier and limit the voltage to about 2.5V, a bit higher than the 2.4V required to turn the UCC25800-Q1 off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgYTyx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The absolute maximum voltage on the DIS/FLT input is 5.5V.

Depending on V1, R3 and temperature range this circuit may or may not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The transistor is an analogue circuit that takes current from the "Enable_Voltage" at a level dependant on that voltage. However, if the "Enable_Voltage" voltage is a low impedance source then the current taken by the transistor will have no effect on circuit operation.

> *The voltage divider will put 1V on the base pin.*

No it won't i.e. very unlikely because the base-emitter region is a forward biased diode and this will probably limit at around 0.8 volts (providing the "Enable_Voltage" source can source hundreds of milliamps into the BJT collector whilst still maintaining a decent output voltage).